# TOP 1 with grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the followin table structure

```
person_id   organization_id
1            1
1            2
1            3
2            4
2            2
```

I want the result set as

```
person_id     organization_id
1               1
2               4
```

means TOP1 of the `person_id`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get top 1 row of each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: whats the ordering of the table here?

Comment: You cannot do this unless you have some other column in your table which defines the order you need. The default ordering you get without an order-by clause cannot be relied on to stay the same. "top 1" has no meaning without specifying the order.

Answer (score 1):

You are using SQL Server, so you can use `row_number()`.  However, you really cannot define `top` without ordering -- the results are not guaranteed.

So, the following will do a `top` without an `order by`:

```
select person_id, min(organization_id)
from t
group by person_id;
```

However, I assume that you intend for the order of the rows to be the intended order.  Alas, SQL tables are *unordered* so the ordering is not valid.  You really need an `id` or `creationdate` or something to specify the order.

All that said, you can try the following:

```
select person_id, organization_id
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person_id order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

It is definitely *not* guaranteed to work.  In my experience, the `order by (select NULL))` returns rows in the same order as the `select` -- although there is no documentation to this effect (that I have found).  Note that in a parallel system on a decent sized table, SQL Server return order has little to do with the order of the rows on the pages or the insert order.

Comment: quick question and it is unrelated...what does partition by clause do?